# Testing TS Express App with Jest: TypeError in Routing

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs, ts-jest

It's my first time using tests and I'm running is some issues with testing my Express API with jest.
The Error occurs in the `ResolutionRouter.ts`:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Router')`

In the main `server.ts` I setup my Routes with `app.use("/", router);`
And the router/index.ts setting up routes and Subrouters:

```
import express from "express";
import ResolutionRouter from "./ResolutionRouter";
import AuthenticationRouter from "./AuthenticationRouter";

const router = express.Router();

router.use("/auth", AuthenticationRouter);
router.use("/resolution", ResolutionRouter);

export default router;
```

In the routes/ResolutionRouter.ts I then define the routes:

```
import express from "express";
import * as ResolutionController from "../controllers/ResolutionController";
import authenticate, {requireRole} from "../middleware/authenticate";

const router = express.Router();  // <-- TypeError thrown here

// routes

export default router;
```

The app itself is running fine with this code, only the tests have some problem.
The AuthenticationRouter is implemented exactly the same, but doesn't throw any Errors which is strange.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the issue was with my tsconfig:

```
"esModuleInterop": true
```

This is required in `compilerOptions`.  Now the test runs fine.